# Vectorization of Product Over

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I am seeking a vectorized form of the following computation:

```
import numpy as np
D = 100
N = 1000
K = 10

X = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (K, N))
T = np.random.uniform(0, 1000, (D, N))
out = np.zeros((D, K))

for i in range(D):
    for j in range(K):
        out[i, j] = np.prod(X[j, :] ** T[i, :])
```

There are einsum-style things I've tried, but the presence of the np.prod is throwing me off a bit.

EDIT: Reduced size of matrices.

Comment: Can you make a more minimal example? I don't have 80gb of memory lying around.

Comment: Your code just results in all zeros for me.  Are these actual inputs?

Comment: That's fine; as long as the expression is correct. The minimal example is for functionality, not utility (I can't upload my original matrices here)

Comment: Looks like you might want `(X ** T[:, None]).prod(-1)`

Comment: @user3483203. You can decrease any of the sizes without harming the concept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to make the broadcasting as explicit as possible - the `None` introduces an additional dummy dimension of size 1:

```
out = np.prod(X[None, :, :] ** T[:, None, :], axis=2)
```

It is easy to see how it works if we recall the shapes: `X.shape = (K, N)`,  `T.shape = (D, N)` and `out.shape = (D, K)`. With the dummy dimension we basically take something of `(1, K, N)` to the power of `(D, 1, N)` which results in `(D, K, N)`. Finally if we reduce via product over the last dimension we get our desired output of `(D, K)`.